# SQL syntax issue (select issue?)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm currently trying to run the following code on a dataset

```
SELECT m.FirstName, m.LastName
FROM Master as m INNER JOIN AllStar as a
ON m.LastName = a.LastName AND m.College = "California"
GROUP BY m.LastName 
HAVING COUNT(a.GamesPlayed) > 2;
```

But I get the error

> No such column: "California"

Why is this the case when I'm trying to compare a column value to the string "California"?

I'm essentially trying to find all basketball players who participated in the all stars > 3 times and are from Cal for a HW assignment but my TA's have not been responding to me :-(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try single quotes ' instead of " double quotes around California

Comment: Your next error will be because you're referencing `FirstName` directly but not grouping on it.  Either add `FirstName` to the `GROUP BY` or remove it from the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Shouldn't the `m.college = 'California'` be part of a `where` clause?

Comment: using sqlite3, i still have the same error even after trying the suggestions :-(

Comment: Why not re-write as 

    SELECT MAX(m.FirstName) AS FirstName, m.LastName
    FROM Master as m INNER JOIN AllStar as a
    ON m.LastName = a.LastName 
    WHERE m.College = 'California'
    GROUP BY m.LastName 
    HAVING COUNT(a.GamesPlayed) > 2;

Comment: @krylor that actually solved my error! Unfortuantely, it isn't producing the correct answer but I will continue to hack at it :-) thank you!

Comment: @Tim,you are welcome,I don't have the schema of your table, else could have done better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Double quotes* are used for `identifiers` that's why `California` string is considered as column name. For string literals use *single quotes*

When you use `Group by` then all the non *aggregate* column should be present in `Group By` clause

```
SELECT m.FirstName, m.LastName
FROM Master as m INNER JOIN AllStar as a
ON m.LastName = a.LastName AND m.College = 'California'
GROUP BY m.FirstName,m.LastName  -- Missing FirstName here
HAVING COUNT(a.GamesPlayed) > 2;
```

Comment: I changed "California" -> 'Califorina' and added the m.FirstName but I'm still getting the same error :-(

Comment: @Tim you should add `m.FirstName` in `group by` already `m.LastName` is present

Comment: sorry, I meant to type that I added in the m.FirstName

Comment: The message says "Error: no such column: 'California'"

Comment: @Tim - Are you sure you replaced double quotes with single quotes

Comment: Yes- this is the exact code that I'm running 
    SELECT m.FirstName, m.LastName
    FROM Master as m INNER JOIN AllStar as a 
    ON m.LastName = a.LastName AND m.College = ‘California’
    GROUP BY m.FirstName, m.LastName
    HAVING COUNT(a.GamesPlayed) > 2;

Comment: @Tim - Try moving the filter to `Where` clause

Comment: hm it didn't seem to do the trick but someone else's comment had a working solution. I can't seem to differentiate the difference between krylor's and mine bcause the yessentially look the same after i move the filter to the where clause

Comment: @Tim - Am not a expert in sqlite as per basic sql standard it should work not sure what is the problem

Comment: Thank you all your help anyways! I appreciate the attempt :)